# Qt overlay(drop-up) box

Tags: qt

I am creating a Qt application where I need to display contents in an overlay box(Please refer to the attached image). The box needs to slide up from behind the bottom dock when a button is pressed and slide down by toggling the button. I tried with a QWidget but couldn't achieve what I wanted. Also I don't know how to list the elements in the overlay box. The elements are dynamic or changing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widgets stacking order is defined by their order in the `QObject` hierarchy tree. The first element is the bottom, and every next is on top of the previous. Children are on top of their parents, in widgets confined within their bounds, in QML free.

If you want that sliding element to appear on top of everything else, just put its parent on top of everything else.

After all it is on top of the bottom control bar, which is on top of the playlist, so you have it all worked out for you.

The same applies if you decide to do the wiser thing and use `QML` instead of `QWidget`. Animation and states are much easier there. Not to mention more specific designs.

Comment: The whole application is written in C++. Can I embed QML in it and have full control? Like access to signals and slots? I would be great if you could give me a rough idea about how to dynamically create the list? I have the data only GUI part is left. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, QML is implemented to use the existing Qt infrastructure, properties, signals and slots as well as any method marked as `QINVOKABLE` can be called from QML. You can implement the core logic separately, encapsulate it and only provide signals and slots to connect to whatever UI you want. Besides connections QML has bindings, which are even faster to work with.